# Audio HTML5 skip to certain moments does not work

Tags: javascript

I want to develop an audio player with buttons that skip to certain moments in the audio (chapters of an audiobook).
Can someone help me?

```
<script>
$('.story').on('click', function(){
  let x = $(240).attr('data-start');
  aud.currentTime=x;
  aud.play();
});`
</script>
```

does not work

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the X the desired time in seconds? Probably if you have the controls enabled for the debug phase it would be easier :)